# How to split UK post code value to return 'outer' part of the code in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to split a UK post code value and return 'outer' part of the code in MC Query Studio using 'LEFT' function but it's not working as exacting.

The scenario is that I have customers who needs to receive a promo code but only if they live in eligible area (postcode) where the promo codes can be used. I'm trying to extract the eligible customers from my Customer DE and check if they exist in my DE with eligible postcodes.

I have a Data Extension with all eligible postcodes but only the first part not the full postcode e.g. 'WC1W' from '**WC1W** 5GH'.

Then I have another Data Extension with the customer's details including a separate field with their postcode, however the field contain the full postcode.

As a first step I'm trying to SELECT the 'postcode' field from the Customer DE and return only the  'outer' part of the code  e.g. 'WC1W' by running the following string in Query Studio:
 `SELECT LEFT(Postcode__c, charindex(' ', Postcode__c) - 1) FROM Customer_DE`

Unfortunately, the function didn't return any values. I tried to hardcode the formula by replacing the field name with actual postcode and it worked but as I mentioned it's not working when I select the field.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right concept down but for the SQL, you'll want to use `SUBSTRING` instead of `LEFT`, so for example, something like this should work:

```
SUBSTRING(Postcode__c, 0, charindex(' ', Postcode__c, 0))
```

Comment: LOL Thanks Jackson! That worked out, could you explain the logic of the formula for example why using '0' and why the 'LEFT' function won't work if that's not much to ask :)  As I said I'm quite new in SQL so will be helpful. Thanks again, really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: The '0' returns the starting position: `CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )` and the same thing with substring: `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )`

Comment: Thank you for explaining it.